# Protractor - How to count elements containing specified text

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to do something I thought would be very simple but has had me stumped for two days now.  I just want to count the number of elements with a specific class that contain a specific line of text.

My code looks like this:

```
element.all(by.className('interaction-thumb-titlebar')).map(function(element) {
    return element.getText();
});
console.log("View names:", viewNames);
```

From what I've read, this should produce something like the following:

```
View names: ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana']
```

And I'll simply search through this array to count whatever I need to count.

The problem of course is that everything, these days, has been changed to promises rather than actual values, meaning what I actually get is this:

```
View names: { closure_uid_209027314: 2004,
  flow_: 
   { events_: {},
     closure_uid_209027314: 1,
     activeFrame_: 
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_209027314: 1954,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     schedulingFrame_: 
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_209027314: 1954,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     eventLoopTask_: null,
     hold_: 
      { _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1437638541678,
        _onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
        _repeat: true },
     yieldCount_: 3 },
  stack_: null,
  parent_: 
   { closure_uid_209027314: 2002,
     flow_: 
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_209027314: 1,
        activeFrame_: [Object],
        schedulingFrame_: [Object],
        shutdownTask_: null,
        eventLoopTask_: null,
        hold_: [Object],
        yieldCount_: 3 },
     stack_: null,
     parent_: 
      { closure_uid_209027314: 2000,
        flow_: [Object],
        stack_: null,
        parent_: [Object],
        callbacks_: [Object],
        state_: 'pending',
        handled_: true,
        pendingNotifications_: false,
        value_: undefined },
     callbacks_: [ [Object] ],
     state_: 'pending',
     handled_: true,
     pendingNotifications_: false,
     value_: undefined },
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  pendingNotifications_: false,
  value_: undefined }
```

I've even tried changing the line `return element.getText();` to `return 'turtle'` and I get exactly the same output.

Can anyone help me?

Andy

Comment: By documentation `map()` will return `A promise that resolves to an array of values returned by the map function.` so you might want to look into the methods available for promises https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/promise.js

Comment: @gillesc, you are a shiny golden god!  It hadn't occured to me that even the map function would be returning a promise.  I shall put an answer to my own question below :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a locator [`by.cssContainingText`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText), which may solve your problem in a bit more elegant way: first parameter it applies is a CSS selector, and the second one is a text you want an element to have. You can then use it in conjunction with a method [`count`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count):

```
var els = element.all(by.cssContainingText('.interaction-thumb-titlebar', 'apple'));
expect(els.count()).toBe(2);
```

Comment: Damnit!  That's so simple!  And just after I've gone and committed my changes!  Thank you muchly :)

Comment: Failed: elements is not defined

Comment: @mark, seems like I made a typo: it should be `element.all(...)`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: expect(els.count()).toBe(2); then console log?

Answer (score 1):

So as @gillesc pointed out to me in the question's comments, the issue I am having is that even the map function returns a promise.  Promises all the way down!  Thankfully, this promise will resolve the promises returned in the map function so the code I needed was like so:

```
element.all(by.className('interaction-thumb-titlebar')).map(function(element) {
    return element.getText();
}).then(function(viewNames){
    console.log("View names:" viewNames);
});
console.log("View names:", viewNames);
```

Now to complete the counting function I needed, the complete solution looks like this:

```
function countElements (css, text) {
    //if no text specified, return number of matching elements with css
    if(!text) {
        return element.all(by.css(css)).then(function(elements){
            return elements.length;
        });
    }
    //if text specified, return number of matching elements with css that have the specifed text
    return element.all(by.css(css)).map(function(element) {
        return element.getText();
    }).then(function(textArray) {
        var numElements = 0;
        for(var i in textArray) {
            if(textArray[i] == text) {
                numElements++;
            }
        }
        return numElements;
    });
}
```

Which I can use like so:

```
expect(countElements('.interaction-thumb-titlebar').toBe(4);
expect(countElements('.interaction-thumb-titlebar', 'apple').toBe(2);
```